# How to stop docstrings in a group applying to all other undocumented functions?

Tags: doxygen

I've noticed strange behavior with doxygen, where function documentation will be applied to multiple functions. eg:

The example below works as expected (only `function_a` is documented).
However using groups causes changed behavior.

```
void function_a(void) {}

/** Document function B */
void function_b(void) {}

void function_c(void) {}
```

---

With a group however the doc-string `Document function B` is applied to all 3 functions.

```
/** \name My ABC Functions
 * \{ */

void function_a(void) {}

/** Document function B */
void function_b(void) {}

void function_c(void) {}

/** \} */
```

---

Is there a way to avoid this?
*Besides having doc-strings for all functions in the group.*

Edit, using `Doxygen version 1.8.11`

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? In the current version I see in both cases that function_b is documented (as expected). I placed the mentioned code in a .c file (and added at the to /** \file */).

Comment: Update, this is related to the configuration (this is a project I've inherited so didnt set up the initial config).

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC`  being enabled in the configuration on the project I was contributing to.

This is disabled by default, and disabling resolved the issue.

See:

```
# If member grouping is used in the documentation and the DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC
# tag is set to YES then doxygen will reuse the documentation of the first
# member in the group (if any) for the other members of the group. By default
# all members of a group must be documented explicitly.
# The default value is: NO.

DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC = YES
```